# SQL query to sort list of clients

Tags: sql

I need to write a SQL query that will return a list of customers who were created in 2020 and who have at least 1 paid order. The final table should contain the following data:

client id

email

date of creation of the first paid order

category of the first paid order

[Client][image: 1]

[Order][image: 2]

Comment: What query have you come up with so far?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example along with any attempts you've made at the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Start with JOINing the tables. Then add a WHERE clause.

Comment: Hi. Join User with Order on user_id and add where condition on user.created_at and order.paid_at

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it :

```
select u.id , u.email , oo.category,oo.created_at 
from users u
cross apply ( select TOP 1 * 
       from orders 
       where o.user_id = u.id 
       order by created_at asc
      ) oo
where u.created between '1-1-2020' and '30-12-2020'
```